# FSharp calling a generic method in a base class

Tags: f#

This question is based on the Functional Random Generators in week one of this course: https://www.coursera.org/course/reactive

The course is Scala based, I'm trying to replicate it in FSharp.

Here's my problem:

I have an abstract generator

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type Generator<'a>() = 
    abstract member Generate: 'a
```

And I have an implementation of that that generates random integers

```
type IntGenerator() =
    inherit Generator<Int32>()

    let rand = new System.Random()
    override this.Generate = rand.Next(Int32.MinValue, Int32.MaxValue)
```

Now, I want to add a Map method to my base class so that new types of generators can be created using code like this

```
let integers = new IntGenerator()        
let booleans = integers.Map (fun x -> x > 0)
```

So, here's how I modified the base class

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type Generator<'a>() = 
    abstract member Generate: 'a
    member this.Map (f:'a -> 'b) = { new Generator<'b>() with member this.Generate = f base.Generate }
```

Unfortunately that call to base.Generate seems to be constraining the type 'b to the same as 'a

I don't get why. I'm sure I'm tripping up on something simple.

Comment: Hi @MaxMalook ... it's a bit more complicated in this case - because `base` is not what you might think ;)

Comment: @CarstenKönig, you're right, it's `base` of the type from the object expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you have to be careful with the instance names of the `member` methods:

I think this should work out:

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type Generator<'a>() = 
    abstract member Generate: unit -> 'a
    static member Map (f:'a -> 'b) = 
        fun (g : Generator<'a>) ->
        { new Generator<'b>() with 
            member this.Generate () = g.Generate () |> f 
        }
```

or if you insist on the member-method:

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type Generator<'a>() = 
    abstract member Generate: unit -> 'a
    member this.Map (f:'a -> 'b) : Generator<'b> = 
        { new Generator<'b>() with 
            member __.Generate () = this.Generate () |> f 
        }
```

note the differences with the `this` and `base` and `__` ;)

**BTW** this will even work without the `unit ->` (as you wrote it):

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type Generator<'a>() = 
    abstract member Generate: 'a
    member this.Map (f:'a -> 'b) : Generator<'b> = 
        { new Generator<'b>() with 
            member __.Generate = this.Generate |> f 
        }
```

*but* I would not recommend this as you get a value-looking method in disguise: `Generate`

### more idiomatic way

```
type Generator<'a> = unit -> 'a

module Generator =
    let map (f:'a -> 'b) (g : Generator<'a>) =
        fun () -> g () |> f

    let intGenerator : Generator<int> =
        let rand = new System.Random()
        fun () -> rand.Next(System.Int32.MinValue, System.Int32.MaxValue)
```

#### fun fact

As you can see here (if you look closely) you will see that this `map` is really just the *Functor*-map for `unit -> *` ;)

**disclaimer** but of course as the generators are sadly impure none of the functor-laws will really hold (if you don't fix your system time)

Comment: without `unit ->` `Generate` would always return the same generated value all the time. Edited: sorry I'm distracted, it's actually a property, with get method ;)

Comment: try it ;) ... it works on my compiler :D (those nasty impure getters)